# Android tablet with gyro and compass

Tags: android, tablet

Is there an Android based tablet which contains both an 3-axis gyro and a compass?

This maybe a silly question, but there are so many different android based devices out there that I don't really know where to start looking.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for this as well for long time. (Oops! same question got negative points and pulled down and closed as this was not related to programming).

But if you are keen on only tablets there's already one Samsung Galaxy Tab which mentions having GyroSensor in its official specification.

Also note support for Gyroscope event is now more in android 2.3 gingerbread. So you may want to have a look at Nexus S running 2.3, here's the official specfication [link text](http://www.google.com/nexus/#/tech-specs)

And a lot more devices will be coming in 2011.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is one called the archos g10 xs. It costs 199.00 at peddlerstore.com 20 bucks for shipping and it has a magnetic stand/keyboard has gps it really has everything. It has an 8" screen
http://peddlerstore.com/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=490&idcategory=0